# Get "time with time zone" from "time without time zone" and the time zone name

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, timezone

First off, I realize `time with time zone` is not recommended. I am going to use it because I'm comparing multiple `time with time zone` values to my current system time regardless of day. I.e. a user says start everyday at 08:00 and finish at 12:00 with THEIR time zone, not the system time zone. So, I have a `time without time zone` column in one table, let's call it `SCHEDULES.time` and I have a **UNIX time zone name** column in another table, let's call it `USERS.tz`.

My system time zone is `'America/Regina'`, which does not use DST and so the offset is always `-06`.

Given a time of '12:00:00' and a tz of 'America/Vancouver' I would like to select the data into a column of type `time with time zone` but I DO NOT want to convert the time to my time zone because the user has effectively said begin at when it is 12:00 in Vancouver, not in Regina.

Thus, doing:

```
SELECT SCHEDULES.time AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz
FROM SCHEDULES JOIN USERS on USERS.ID=SCHEDULES.USERID;
```

results (at the moment) in:

```
'10:00:00-08'
```

but I really want:

```
'12:00:00-08'
```

I can't find any documentation relating to applying a time zone to a time, other then `AT TIME ZONE`. Is there a way to accomplish this without character manipulation or other hacks?

**UPDATE:**
This can be accomplished by using string concatenation, casting, and the Postgres time zone view as such:

```
select ('12:00:00'::text || utc_offset::text)::timetz
from pg_timezone_names
where name = 'America/Vancouver';
```

However, this is fairly slow. There must be a better way, no?

**UPDATE 2:**
I apologize for the confusion. The `SCHEDULES` table DOES NOT use `time with time zone`, I am trying to SELECT a `time with time zone` by combining values from a `time without time zone` and a `text` time zone name.

**UPDATE 3:**
Thanks to all those involved for their (heated) discussion. :) I have been convinced to abandon my plan to use a `time with time zone` for my output and instead use a `timestamp with time zone` as it performs well, is more readable, and solves another problem that I was going to run into, time zones that roll into new dates. IE. '2011-11-21 23:59' in 'America/Vancouver' is '2011-11-22' in 'America/Regina'.

**UPDATE 4:**
As I said in my last update, I have chosen the answer that @MichaelKrelin-hacker first proposed and @JonSkeet finalized. That is, a `timestamp with time zone` as my final output is a better solution. I ended up using a query like:

```
SELECT timezone(USERS.tz, now()::date + SCHEDULES.time)
FROM SCHEDULES
JOIN USERS ON USERS.ID = SCHEDULES.USERID;
```

The `timezone()` format was rewritten by Postgres after I entered `(current_date + SCHEDULES.time) AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz` into my view.

Comment: Does your real SQL have a join in it? At the moment I can't see how you're mapping one to the other. If so, please show a short but *complete* query.

Comment: Yes, the join was implied.
    SELECT SCHEDULES.time AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz from SCHEDULES
    JOIN USERS on USERS.ID=SCHEDULES.USERID

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't see why that's necessary, since he's given us specific data examples. If it helps, you can pretend the complete query is `SELECT '12:00:00'::TIME AT TIME ZONE 'America/Vancouver';`, which gives `10:00:00-08` on the OP's GMT-0600 system.

Comment: @ruakh: The join is *absolutely* necessary for the actual query - and clearly if that had been messed up, it would have affected everything else.

Comment: This has intrigued me now. It sounds like it should work. I'm downloading and installing PostgreSQL to try it. Prepare for stupid questions...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Are you just speaking hypothetically here? Because if you try the query I just named, you see exactly the behavior he describes (modulo your own time-zone). Yes, if he were messing up his join he'd see other problems, but it's clear that he isn't, so what's your point?

Comment: His point is that he didn't really know how it works, but tried to find the problem elsewhere. But he's curious enough to figure it out, I love this attitude. Seriously.

Comment: @ruakh: My point is that it's good to have a *complete* query rather than a partial one. It *wasn't* clear that he isn't messing up the join, and I've seen enough questions where the OP assumes an error is in one place when actually it's in another to decide that it's a bad idea to make assumptions. Now for your complete query - is "TIME" actually equivalent to "TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE", or is it assuming a *local* time zone? Big difference, and *I* don't know enough PostgreSQL to say which it is.

Comment: @JonSkeet, time is what he declared and he said he opted in for time with time zone. Which means, that times are stored as *UTC* times with time zones.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: No, he's declared a time *without* time zone column in his table: "So, I have a time without timezone column one table"

Comment: @JonSkeet: In recent versions of PostgreSQL, `TIME` is exactly equivalent to `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, yes. (See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-datetime.html.) Re: having a complete query: I think it depends. In a question about a bug in a program or query, it's good to give a small complete version that demonstrates the bug; but here, he's just describing normal PostgreSQL behavior. If a question asked what `int? num = null;` meant in C#, would you expect to see a full working C# program that included it?

Comment: @JonSkeet, oops, my bad.

Comment: @ruakh: No, but that's not the equivalent here. It's *part* of a query. If someone asked why a *statement* was giving the wrong result, but only one expression was given, I'd ask to see the complete statement.

Comment: @JonSkeet: So if someone asked, "I want to get seventeen divided by two, i.e. 8.5, but `(17 / 2)` gives me 8. I've managed to figure out that this is because it's 'integer division', and what I need is 'floating-point division'. How do I get it to do floating-point division?", you would reply, "Please give a complete statement that uses this expression"? That seems . . . unhelpful.

Comment: @ruakh: If they said "(x / y) gives me 8" then I'd ask to see the declarations of `x` and `y`. Put it this way - *with* the join, I'd know how to proceed. Without *either* the join *or* your complete query, I didn't know how to make any progress. Is it *so* unreasonable to ask for a short but complete example here?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Fair enough. Not so unreasonable, no. :-)

Comment: @ruakh: Let's just hope it was worth it - I *think* my answer makes sense, but if you could check it, that would be very helpful...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, it looks good to me. +1. And now that you've given a useful answer, I understand your request much better. Previously it sounded to me like, "I know nothing about the topic, but maybe your question is wrongheaded and you've got a bug elsewhere that I *would* know something about", whereas now in retrospect I see that you were really saying, "I know nothing about the topic, but I know a lot about related topics (time-zones in other contexts), and am willing to put some effort into learning about this and helping you out, but need a bit of a hand getting started." Mea culpa. I sh

Comment: ouldn't have assumed the worst.

Comment: @ruakh: No problem - glad we came out on the same side, and now I've actually got an alternative query which *may* be good enough for the OP with no other changes...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WARNING: PostgreSQL newbie (see comments on the question!). I know a bit about time zones though, so I know what makes *sense* to ask.

It looks to me like this is basically an unsupported situation (unfortunately) when it comes to `AT TIME ZONE`. Looking at the [AT TIME ZONE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) documentation it gives a table where the "input" value types are only:

- timestamp without time zone
- timestamp with time zone
- time with time zone

We're missing the one you want: time *without* time zone. What you're asking is *somewhat* logical, although it does depend on the date... as different time zones can have different offsets depending on the date. For example, 12:00:00 Europe/London *may* mean 12:00:00 UTC, or it may mean 11:00:00 UTC, depending on whether it's winter or summer.

On my system, having set the system time zone to America/Regina, the query

```
SELECT ('2011-11-22T12:00:00'::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) 
                               AT TIME ZONE 'America/Vancouver'
```

gives me `2011-11-22 14:00:00-06` as a result. That's not *ideal*, but it does at least give the instant point in time (I think). I believe that if you fetched that with a client library - or compared it with another `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` - you'd get the right result. It's just the text conversion that then uses the *system* time zone for output.

Would that be good enough for you? Can you either change your `SCHEDULES.time` field to be a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` field, or (at query time) combine the time from the field with a date to create a timestamp without time zone?

EDIT: If you're happy with the "current date" it *looks* like you can just change your query to:

```
SELECT (current_date + SCHEDULES.time) AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz
from SCHEDULES JOIN USERS on USERS.ID=SCHEDULES.USERID
```

Of course, the current *system* date may not be the same as the current date *in the local time zone*. I *think* this will fix that part...

```
SELECT ((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz)::DATE + schedules.time)
       AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz
from SCHEDULES JOIN USERS on USERS.ID=SCHEDULES.USERID
```

In other words:

- Take the current instant
- Work out the local date/time in the user's time zone
- Take the date of that
- Add the schedule time to that date to get a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`
- Use `AT TIME ZONE` to apply the time zone to that local date/time

I'm sure there's a better way, but I *think* it makes sense.

You should be aware that in some cases this could fail though:

- What do you want the result to be for a time of 01:30 on a day when the clock skips from 01:00 to 02:00, so 01:30 doesn't occur at all?
- What do you want the result to be for a time of 01:30 on a day when the clock goes back from 02:00 to 01:00, so 01:30 occurs twice?

Comment: Didn't you end up with what I started my answer with? :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Not really - I've ended up by suggesting that `SCHEDULES.time` should be a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` field; I don't see that in your (deleted) answer.

Comment: Yes, because, as you know by now, I (wrongly) assumed it is time without time zone and as you can see by the results, it works the same.

Comment: What I mean is that we more or less leave the OP with the same results, which is not exactly what he wanted.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: No, these results are better: they have the wrong hours-field *and* the wrong time-zone, that is, they have the right time-zone for their hours-field (so they correctly identify the right point in time). Whereas the OP's original results were giving the wrong hours-field but the *right* time-zone, which meant that they had the wrong time-zone for their hours-field (so they identified the wrong time-of-day).

Comment: @ruakh, how is `14:00:00-06` different from `14:00:00-06`? Let me repeat — I'm talking about what I *started* my answer with.

Comment: Nevermind, though, if you prefer `14:00:00-06` over `14:00:00-06`, I'm fine with it. I know I can't help the OP in a sensible way, anyway beyond that, anyway.

Comment: This has helped point me in a new direction but I don't think I am going to change the `SCHEDULES.time` column. Instead, I will probably select a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE using something like `SELECT (CURRENT_DATE::timestamp + SCHEDULES.time)::timestamp at time zone USERS.tz` (join excluded for brevity)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Sorry, I can't see what you started your answer with, since you've deleted it. The first version of your answer that I saw is the one that I commented on, wherein you suggested that the UTC-offset be set at time-of-insertion, rather than at time-of-query. If an earlier version said something different, then I have no idea about it!

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: If your original suggestion *had* given 14:00:00-06, I think that would have been fine. I believe it *actually* gives 12:00:00-06 though. That's what I saw on my box, anyway. Did you try it and see 14:00:00-06? If so, I'll give it another go and see what I messed up...

Comment: @gabrielsond: See my edit for a possibly-more-reliable version using `current_timestamp` instead. It depends on exactly which date you're trying to use.

Comment: @ruakh, I'm talking about it's beginning, not version.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, I have tried it. But seriously — nevermind, I didn't mean to argue really and I don't think that continuing this will get OP anywhere. I've tried to be helpful, now it's your turn and you're doing great.

Comment: This solution works best for me because it handles date rollover. One note, I have chosen to use `SELECT (current_date + SCHEDULES.time) AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz from SCHEDULES JOIN USERS on USERS.ID=SCHEDULES.USERID` over `SELECT ((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz)::DATE + schedules.time) AT TIME ZONE USERS.tz from SCHEDULES JOIN USERS on USERS.ID=SCHEDULES.USERID` because the later actually makes the comparison invalid in my circumstances although I can see why it SHOULD be used in OTHER circumstances. Thanks @JonSkeet and @MichaelKrelin-hacker for the advice & solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demo how to calculate the times without casting to text:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE schedule(t time, tz text);
INSERT INTO schedule values
 ('12:00:00', 'America/Vancouver')
,('12:00:00', 'US/Mountain')
,('12:00:00', 'America/Regina');

SELECT s.t AT TIME ZONE s.tz
        - p.utc_offset
        + EXTRACT (timezone from now()) * interval '1s'
FROM   schedule s
JOIN   pg_timezone_names p ON s.tz = p.name;
```

Basically you have to subtract the UTC offset and add the offset of your local time zone to arrive at the given time zone.

You can speed up the calculation by hardcoding your local offset. In your case (America/Regina) that should be:

```
SELECT s.t AT TIME ZONE s.tz
        - p.utc_offset
        - interval '6h'
FROM   schedule s
JOIN   pg_timezone_names p ON s.tz = p.name;
```

As `pg_timezone_names` is a view and not actually a system table, it is rather slow - just like the demonstrated variant with casting to text representation and back.

I would store the time zone abbreviations and take the double cast via `text` without joining in `pg_timezone_names` for optimum performance.

---

### FAST solution

The **culprit** that's slowing you down is `pg_timezone_names`. After some testing I found that `pg_timezone_abbrevs` is far superior. Of course, you have to save *correct* **time zone abbreviations** instead of time zone names to achieve this. Time zone *names* take DST into consideration automatically, time zone *abbreviations* are basically just codes for a time offset. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

> A time zone abbreviation, for example `PST`. Such a specification merely
>   defines a particular offset from UTC, in contrast to full time zone names
>   which can imply a set of daylight savings transition-date rules as well.

Have a look at these test results or try yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM  pg_timezone_names;
```

Total runtime: **541.007** ms

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_abbrevs;
```

Total runtime: **0.523** ms

**Factor 1000**. Whether you go with your idea to cast to `text` and back to `timetz` or with my method to compute the time is not important. Both methods are very fast. Just don't use `pg_timezone_names`.

Actually, as soon as you save time zone abbreviations, you can take the casting route without **any** additional joins. Use the abbreviation instead of the utc_offset. Results are accurate as per your definition.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE schedule(t time, abbrev text);
INSERT INTO schedule values
 ('12:00:00', 'PST')  -- 'America/Vancouver'
,('12:00:00', 'MST')  -- 'US/Mountain'
,('12:00:00', 'CST'); -- 'America/Regina'

-- calculating
SELECT s.t AT TIME ZONE s.abbrev
     - a.utc_offset
     + EXTRACT (timezone from now()) * interval '1s'
FROM   schedule s
JOIN   pg_timezone_abbrevs a USING (abbrev);

-- casting (even faster!)
SELECT (t::text || abbrev)::timetz
FROM   schedule s;
```

Comment: I think the OP in fact wanted to avoid join rather than character manipulations, he was complaining about his query being slow and I think it's mostly because of the join.

Comment: Great answer! Unfortunately, joining the pg_timezone_names view is still too slow compared to the option of using a timestamp with timezone and NOT joining that view. Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: That's true, @ErwinBrandstetter. How do these constructs account for daylight saving, btw? Or do they?

Comment: It's not clear whether `pg_timezone_names` always gives the *current* offset from UTC, or the *standard time* offset from UTC. Basically we need to know what date the OP wants applied to the time, as that significantly affects the result.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: The information for the time offset or time zone has to come from *somewhere*.

Comment: @JonSkeet: [I quote the docs here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/view-pg-timezone-names.html): `Therefore, the associated information changes across local DST boundaries. The displayed information is computed based on the current value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, that's what I agreed with already, my concern was what Jon expressed as well. And your quote from the docs answers that. But it precludes storing the offsets.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Sorry, didn't want to repeat myself, that was an editing artefact. And yes, it seems, as long as we want exact times at all times, calculation will be slow. However, the casting via text **can** be fast, because we don't need to join in the system view for that.

Comment: It sounds like the best way to store the times may be in `varchar`. And if the `timestamp` is used instead of `time`, the best thing may be `('2000-01-01 'time||' '||tz)::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'America/Regina'`

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: storing `text` instead of `time` would give a small performance advantage, especially with the casting route. If you safe `hh24:mi` format it would also occupy a bit less space on disc (6 bytes versus 8 bytes for `time`). But you lose the comfort of automatic type constraints and faster calculations. Either way, relatively unimportant in respect to performance. The important part is in my amended answer.

Comment: @gabrielsond: please see my amended answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think we all had the wrong angle here. All the OP needs is to store the time zone abbreviation instead of the time zone name and use that for casting. See my amended answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I'm not convinced it's the best approach, to be honest. Time zone abbreviations are generally discouraged in wider circles for reasons of ambiguity. Fundamentally the OP still isn't specifying which date is the one to use for the local time, and that's *important* when performing a time zone conversion.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Right, that ambiguity remains, or rather, these 2 sources of ambiguity. But then again, that's as good as a `time with time zone` gets and why it's use is generally discouraged.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I'm not sure why that's as good as it gets - my solution *doesn't* use ambiguous time zone abbreviations, and currently explicitly uses the current date (with the more complex solution using the current date in the time zone of the user), but can easily be changed to use a specific date. It looks like all the information *is there*, it just needs to be used carefully.

Comment: @Jon My solution solves the problem at hand: **degrading performance**. With the type `time with time zone` and the given definition of the problem *exact* calculations are not feasible. It would be absurd to worry about the minor ambiguity that time zone abbreviations add to the scenario. `NULL + 1` is still `NULL`. You argue all information was there, but it's in your interpretation only. `timetz` is broken by design and the PostgreSQL developers concur, even if it is defined in the SQL standard. Using it only makes sense, if exact calculations over time zones are not required to begin with.

Comment: @Jon Using a timestamp instead is clearly the way to go, no argument about that. With timestamps it makes sense to avoid whatever small amount of ambiguity time zone abbreviations add to the scenario.