# How to get all the same date & time independently of the timezone

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

How should I store my "dates + times" in a PostgreSQL database?

This is what I want to achieve:

1. How can I have all the entries that occurred on (for example) 1 January 2012 00:00:00 local time anywhere in the world?
2. Display all the entries sorted by date according to UTC time. (2012 New Year Eve in New York is more recent than the New Year in London).

How should I store my data? I have read that PostgreSQL stores all time in UTC internally ([PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)), so my users timezone is in fact lost.

I think I should use one column with type "timestamp without timezone":

- Point 1 is easy.
- And with another column of type "String" I will store the timezone string (e.g : America/New_York)
  but then, point 2 seems still hard to do ....

I hope I am clear.

Edit new idea: I think with storing two timestamps: one without timezone (1. ok) and one with timezone (2. ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PostgreSQL stores all timestamps as UTC internally. For a `timestamp with time zone` the time zone offset is only applied to adjust the time to UTC, but is not stored explicitly.

I would not store the *timezone string* or even less a time zone abbreviation (those are not precise). This can later require expensive computation, because you have to consider daylight savings time and other oddities of the international time regime.

You can either store the time zone offset as interval (takes **12 bytes**) or a numerical amount of seconds (takes **4 bytes** as integer) like I demonstrate in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764998/939860).

Or, like you already proposed: store the local timestamp in addition to the UTC timestamp (takes **8 bytes**). That would make your tasks easy. Consider the following demo::

```
-- DROP TABLE tbl;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (id int, ts_tz timestamp with time zone, ts timestamp);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
 (1,'2012-1-1 00:00+01','2012-1-1 00:00+01')
,(2,'2012-1-1 00:00+02','2012-1-1 00:00+02')
,(3,'2012-1-1 00:01+03','2012-1-1 00:01+03')
,(4,'2012-1-1 00:02+04','2012-1-1 00:02+04');
```

Query for question 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ts = '2012-1-1 00:00'::timestamp;

 id |         ts_tz          |         ts
----+------------------------+---------------------
  1 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00+01 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00
  2 | 2011-12-31 23:00:00+01 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00
```

Query for question 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY ts_tz;

 id |         ts_tz          |         ts
----+------------------------+---------------------
  4 | 2011-12-31 21:02:00+01 | 2012-01-01 00:02:00
  3 | 2011-12-31 22:01:00+01 | 2012-01-01 00:01:00
  2 | 2011-12-31 23:00:00+01 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00
  1 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00+01 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00
```

The **tricky part**  with this solution may be to enter the local timestamp. That's easy as long as all data is entered locally. But it needs consideration if you enter data for, say, New York in Los Angeles. Use the [`AT TIME ZONE` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) for that:

```
SELECT ('2012-1-1 00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::timestamp
     , ('2012-1-1 00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')::timestamp

      timezone       |      timezone
---------------------+---------------------
 2011-12-31 19:00:00 | 2011-12-31 16:00:00
```

Note how I use a timestamp **with time zone** as input. `AT TIME ZONE` gives different results for timestamps with or without time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could store the date as a string and use ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 so you also store the timezone.
Or indeed for more comparison options store timestamp and timezone in 2 different columns.

Comment: storing dates/times as a string is a very dirty way of doing things and should be avoided

Comment: Isn't a date/time field in the database always a string?
And I agree with you for comparison in queries but if thats not required storing it as ISO 8601 string shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Unless postgresql does something very different from other database engines, then no, datetime is never stored as a string (normally it is an integer value which represents an amount of time defined from a particular date/time in the past)