# How do I "combine" an un-zoned date and a time zone?

Tags: swift, date, timezone

My question is very similar to [Get "time with time zone" from "time without time zone" and the time zone name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233351/get-time-with-time-zone-from-time-without-time-zone-and-the-time-zone-name) (I think). I just want to do it in Swift.

Anyway, I am trying to write a function with the following signature:

```
func combine(_ date: Date, with timeZone: TimeZone) -> Date?
```

What it does is that it basically takes in a date and returns a "zoned" date. If the date does not exist in the time zone, it returns `nil`.

To avoid being an XY question, here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm asking the user for a date and a time zone and I want to combine these two into one single `Date`.

I'll try my best to explain. I will express dates in the format of `timeIntervalFrom1970` to make it as clear as possible.

Say I pass in 0 as the date and GMT-1 as the time zone, it'll return 3600. 0 is 1970-1-1 00:00:00. 1970-1-1 00:00:00 in GMT-1 is 1970-1-1 01:00:00 in GMT, which is 3600.

This is how I tried to implement this:

```
return date.addingTimeInterval(-timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: date))
```

This seems to work most but not all of the time. However, I don't think it returns the correct results if DST gets involved and the whole thing becomes messy. It also feels "math-ish". I would prefer an approach without math, using only the Foundation API methods.

So, **How can I implement this method?**

Comment: There is no "zoned Date", a `Date` is a absolute point in time. – What you can do is to create a Date from *date components* (year, month, day, hour, minute, second), a time zone *and a calendar.*

Comment: @MartinR I am aware of that yes. That's why I am struggling to do this. I am using eureka forms and the first table row is actually a `DateTimeRow` I can only get a `Date` from that. And I want to convert this date to a new date according to the time zone selected.

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but adjusting by the *difference* of the GMT offsets between the local and the other timezone should work. Alternatively you can convert Date->DateComponents->Date, using the local timezone for the first conversion and the other timezone for the second conversion.

Comment: There is a general problem: What if a user selects a date/time which does *not exist* in the other timezone (because the clocks are adjusted forward for DST)? What result would you expect in that case? – For example, a user in India (which does not have DST, as far as I know) could select "2017/03/26 02:30 Germany", which is does not exist.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes! I forgot to consider that. I think I'll just make it return nil. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the API gives you a `Date`, but you want to interpret
that as "2017/08/18 8:08" in some given time zone. Assuming that
the eureka forms UI element uses the timezone of the current calendar
for display, you can convert the date to `DateComponents`, and back
to a `Date` with a different timezone.

```
func combine(_ date: Date, with timeZone: TimeZone) -> Date? {
    var cal = Calendar.current
    let comp = cal.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
    cal.timeZone = timeZone
    return cal.date(from: comp)
}
```

`nil` will be returned if the day/time combination does not exist
in the other timezone.

Comment: When I select "today 8:37:37" and I print the date I get. It's "2017-08-18 07:37:37 +0000". The device time zone is in GMT+1. Apparently the API converts the selected date to UTC. Does this "use the timezone of the current calendar for display" as you have said?

Comment: Then how should I determine whether it uses the time zone of the current calendar for display?

Comment: Which target timezone did you choose? What is the `date` before and after conversion?

Comment: Wait, I am only printing the date here though. I am just trying to figure out whether Eureka uses the time zone of the current calendar for display. This has nothing to do with time zones right? I am not even using the value of the time zone row.

Comment: @Sweeper: `"today 8:37:37"` *is* "2017-08-18 07:37:37 +0000" in the GMT+1 timezone.

Comment: I think I get it now, so it _does_ "use the time zone of the current calendar to display the date". But when I do `combine(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0), with: TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -3600)!)?.timeIntervalSince1970` in the playground it apparently returns 7200. I expected 3600 though.

Comment: @Sweeper: That looks correct to me. `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)` is "1970-01-01 01:00" in your GMT+1 timezone. That is interpreted as "1970-01-01 01:00 -3600" which is "1970-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" – The difference between your GMT+1 and the target GMT-1 timezone is 7200.

Comment: Oh after I see the steps in between I understand now. Thank you!